# jQuery .animate() top property issue

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-animate

I have div element width position:absolute,

```
$(page).animate({left: dispX });
```

is working fine.
 
but the following is adding various additional padding to element:

```
$(page).animate({top: dispY });
```

while the following is working fine:

```
$(page).offset({top: dispY });
```

Comment: Can you provide a JSFiddle with HTML and CSS? Need more context to give an accurate answer.

Comment: Strange, but on the JSFiddle it works. How can I debug this?

Comment: Is your Fiddle fully align with your site environment or minimal code? Please share the Fiddle, it's useful. Do you happen to have a live site?

Comment: Here http://jsfiddle.net/quz4gkn5/, unfortunately, I have no hosting.